# PIXI.js particles clumping in the corner. Can't figure it out

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, pixi.js

So, I'm trying to creeate a web of particles with PIXI.js in Angular 9.
Here is my service that I'm injecting into the root:

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import * as PIXI from 'pixi.js'

class Particle {
  x: number;
  y: number;
  xDirection: number;
  yDirection: number;
  radius: number;
  graphicCorespondent: PIXI.Graphics;
  
  constructor(){
    this.x = Math.random() * window.innerWidth;
    this.y = Math.random() * window.innerHeight;
    this.xDirection = Math.random();
    this.xDirection *= Math.ceil(Math.random()*2) == 2 ? 1 : -1;
    this.yDirection = Math.random();
    this.yDirection *= Math.ceil(Math.random()*2) == 2 ? 1 : -1;
    // this.xDirection = 1;
    // this.yDirection = 1;
    this.radius = 1 + Math.random() * 3;
  }
}

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class ParticlesService {
  app = new PIXI.Application({width: window.innerWidth, height: window.innerHeight});
  density = 3000;
  particles = [];
  velocity = 1;

  constructor() {
    window.onload = () => {
      document.body.appendChild(this.app.view);
      this.app.renderer.backgroundColor = 0xFFFFFF;
      this.app.renderer.view.style.position = "fixed";
      this.app.renderer.view.style.display = "block";
      this.app.renderer.view.style.left = '0';
      this.app.renderer.view.style.top = '0';
      this.app.renderer.view.style.zIndex = '-1';
      // window.onresize = () => {
      //   this.app.renderer.resize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight)
      // }
    }
  }

  init(){
    for(let i=0; i<this.density; i++){
      const particle = new Particle();
      const gr = new PIXI.Graphics();
      gr.beginFill(0x000000);
      gr.drawCircle(particle.x, particle.y, particle.radius);
      gr.endFill();

      particle.graphicCorespondent = gr;
      this.particles.push(particle)

      this.app.stage.addChild(gr)
    }
    this.app.ticker.add((delta) => {
      this.animate(delta);
    });
    this.app.ticker.start();
  }

  animate(delta){
    this.particles.forEach((particle, index) => {
      
      if(particle.x > window.innerWidth) particle.x = 0;  
      if(particle.y > window.innerHeight) particle.y = 0;  
      if(particle.x < 0) particle.x = window.innerWidth;  
      if(particle.y < 0) particle.y = window.innerHeight; 

      particle.graphicCorespondent.x = particle.x + delta * particle.xDirection;
      particle.graphicCorespondent.y = particle.y + delta * particle.yDirection;

      particle.x = particle.graphicCorespondent.x;
      particle.y = particle.graphicCorespondent.y;
      
    })
    this.app.render()
  }
}
```

I managed to get this far, it works....but the particles tend to clump in the bottom right corner everytime.

If I remove the "edge collision detection":

```js
if(particle.x > window.innerWidth) particle.x = 0;  
if(particle.y > window.innerHeight) particle.y = 0;  
if(particle.x < 0) particle.x = window.innerWidth;  
if(particle.y < 0) particle.y = window.innerHeight;
```

It seems to work fine, but the particles will fly into infinity.
Otherwise... they tend to clump up in the bottom right corner and I don't understand why.

[Screenshot of the clumping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h6vLV.png)

I wasted a full day on this one, and I still can't figure why it does that.
I created a fresh Angular app using the CLI and the only thing that I created was this service. Same results.

The `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">` is present.

Rescaling seems to work.

Width and Height are corect.

The particle.x and particle.graphicCorespondent.x are equal at the end of the tick.

Also, the particles seems to disappear and reappear before they hit the edge most of the time.

If anyone could take a look over this one, I would be extremly grateful. It's driving me mad.

I tried slicing the particle once it's out of the screen and create another one. It creates another one but it seems to be static afterwards.

I tried looping directly through the `stage.children`, same result.

Also tried reading the x and y values of the particles by accessing the getBounds() method on the particle.graphicCorespondent. Same value, not relevant.

**Edit:** I get the same results in Chrome and in Firefox.

**PIXI.js version: 5.2.3**

**Angular version: 9.1.1**

Comment: Can you try reducing number of particles ("density") to 1 and observe how this single particle behaves?

Comment: Just did that. The canvas appears to be empty while just one is present. Only when I got the density up to 10 I got some particles show up. So maybe the canvas is bigger than it shows? But why? How?

Comment: Also, I let the app run overnight. It seems that they will all remain on screen, it's just that more particles will show up on the bottom right.

Comment: Ok - so i think you should focus on analyzing behaviour of single particle. If it doesnt shows 1 particle on screen then something may be incorrectly set indeed - like canvas vs window size etc.

Comment: Also try starting with something simple - for example: try to display static (not moving) particle in the middle of screen, and in each corner - this should give indication about the screen/canvas situation.

Comment: If you could make a working example at say codepen,jsbin,etc Id be happy to have a look, dont know angular enough to know how to set this up.  But while Im here `this.xDirection = Math.random();this.xDirection *= Math.ceil(Math.random()*2) == 2 ? 1 : -1;` can be written as `this.xDirection=(Math.random()*2) -1`  and if the collision detection is meant to loop to the other side your code is wrong `if(particle.x > window.innerWidth) particle.x = 0;` should be `if(particle.x > window.innerWidth) particle.x = particle.x-window.innerWidth;` same fix for other lines

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error is in the way you draw your sprites.  Specifically....
`gr.drawCircle(particle.x, particle.y, particle.radius);`
Your saying draw a circle at x and y with such a radius.  This draw operation will be done relative to the x,y of gr.  So then later when you draw the sprite on the canvas the dot will have an offset from the x and y of gr.
So what you actually wanted was....
`gr.drawCircle(0, 0, particle.radius);`
Here's a working example for you to look at....
https://codesandbox.io/s/so-pixijs-particles-clumping-in-the-corner-cant-figure-it-out-tsccz?file=/index.js

Comment: Please make working example in the future.  You got lucky that it drove me nuts I couldnt see the error when it all looked right that I had to make a working example to figure it out ;) but I wouldnt always rely on my obsessive nature :P  Hope it brings you some peace as well.

Comment: but isn't the x and y the position of the circle? where I need it to be drawn? I thought it's the origin of the circle.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/so-pixijs-particles-clumping-in-the-corner-cant-figure-it-out-pmtk6?file=/index.js  I made it only draw one graphic at 0,0  but made the circle be drawn at 200,200 and note the circle is at 200,200.  Now you change the x,y to 100,0 and notice the circle shift 100 to the right.  This shows that the draw commands you give are relative to its parents (the graphics) x,y.  I just checked the docs (Ive only been learning this for a few days) and it doesnt state that anywhere I could see.  Might see if this can be added to the docs as it could confuse others aswell.

Comment: I answered this question with the assumption that it rendered the graphic and displayed that, whereas the truth is it draws it every frame relative to the x,y.  Ill update my answer soon to reflect that, I just wanna look at a couple of things first.  Oh, and I updated the example, even added some resize stuff since it was there but commented out, just incase it helps.